# Is there a alternative solution for Amazon SQS-FIFO Queue to maintain Order of events that are received from S3?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-sqs, fifo

I have 10 lambda functions for a project and one router lambda that copies the file from SFTP and place it in S3 then S3 triggers the lambda function according to the type of the file.

My scenario is to maintain the order of the file events for one type of file.

I thought to use  SQS-FIFO to queue the S3 events but later found that SQS-FIFO is not supporting S3 to process the events in Order they pushed.
What is best alternative solution for this?

Comment: Where in your flow are you using SQS? You mention "S3 triggers the lambda function according to the type of the file", but you don't mention when the SQS queue is involved, or why it is being used. Please Edit your question to explain your desired flow.

Comment: I have corrected it now.

Comment: Why are you wanting to use SQS? Why not have S3 simply trigger the appropriate Lambda function as soon as the 'router lambda' copies the file across? Do the files take a long time to process?

Comment: Current design is triggering the lambda when the uploading finished. I should not run the  lambda parallelly and only one instance should run it. The new approach is to handle the disaster cases where i need to process the files in FIFO manner to maintain the data in order.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears your situation is:

- Files appear in **SFTP**
- Your "Router Lambda" copies files from SFTP to an **Amazon S3 bucket**
- Depending upon the type of file that was copied, you want a specific **Lambda function** to process that file
- For each file type, you want to process the files **in the order that they were received** from the 'router lambda' and you do not want the same filetype being processed in parallel with another file of the same type

I would recommend that, rather than having Amazon S3 send a message to the Amazon SQS queue, you have your 'router lambda' do it instead. Currently, the 'router lambda' is copying the file "according to the type of file". You just need to **add one more command that sends a message to the FIFO SQS queu**e with details of the object that was copied. This takes the place of having S3 send the message to the SQS queue.

Thus, you would have:

- 10 Lambda functions (one for each file type, presumably)
- 10 Amazon SQS FIFO queues (one for each file type)

The 'router lambda' would:

- Copy the file from SFTP to S3
- Push a message into the appropriate SQS FIFO queue with details of the file copied

The SQS FIFO queue will trigger the appropriate Lambda function to process the file. Note that multiple files can be passed to a single Lambda invocation, so make sure to iterate through the `events['Records']` array. Or, if you only want to process one file per invocation, set the Lambda function's batch size to 1.

See also: [New for AWS Lambda – SQS FIFO as an event source | AWS Compute Blog](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/new-for-aws-lambda-sqs-fifo-as-an-event-source/)